# Timer or Code not sticking to schedule

Tags: excel, vba

I have code where I am accessing an xml feed for live currency data. I need to capture the price every 3 minutes, and it has to be pretty spot on, otherwise it will throw off the other calculations.

I set up a timer to run the code every 3 minutes,  or whatever interval I choose.

I started noticing slippage, which was a second or two at first but has turned into 10 seconds in places. Any thoughts?

```
Sub xmlData()

Dim aSwitch As String: aSwitch = Sheet2.[Switch].Value
Dim aSymbol As String: aSymbol = Sheet2.[Symbol].Value

'check [switch] status
If aSwitch = "OFF" Then
    MsgBox "Switch is OFF!", vbCritical, "Program Status"
    Exit Sub
End If

'MsgBox "Program is ON!", vbCritical, "Program Status"

'refresh xml data
Dim iMap As XmlMap
Set iMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)
iMap.DataBinding.LoadSettings "http://****.com/webservice/v1/symbols/" & aSymbol & "/quote"
iMap.DataBinding.Refresh

'dim inputs
Dim aStart As String: aStart = Sheet2.Range("c3").Text
Dim aInterval As String: aInterval = Sheet2.Range("d3").Text
Dim aStatus As String: aStatus = Sheet2.[Status].Value
'oth
Dim aSecurity As String: aSecurity = Sheet2.[Security].Value
Dim aPrice As String: aPrice = Sheet2.[Price].Value
Dim aDatetime As String: aDatetime = Sheet2.[DateTime].Value

'separate adatetime
Dim aDate As String: aDate = Mid(aDatetime, 1, 10)
Dim aTime As String: aTime = Mid(aDatetime, 12, 10)

'Time actual
Dim aTimeNow As String: aTimeNow = Format(Now(), "HH:mm:ss")

'copy xml data to table
Dim aRow As Long

aRow = Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

Sheet2.Cells(aRow, 1).Value = aDate
Sheet2.Cells(aRow, 2).Value = aTime
Sheet2.Cells(aRow, 3).Value = aSecurity
Sheet2.Cells(aRow, 4).Value = aPrice
Sheet2.Cells(aRow, 5).Value = aTimeNow

'start timer for reload
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(aInterval), "xmlData"

End Sub
```

EDIT 160627

Is it possible the XML is not fetching right away?

Comment: Perhaps your procedure takes time to execute, so try calculating the "next" time *before* doing anything else.

Comment: Better yet, calculate the scheduled time in absolute terms, rather than as a differential from `Now`

Comment: TW-so like setting the timer in the beginning? ok...CN-im not sure how to calculate in absolute terms.

Comment: @NickFleetwood add Interval to last scheduled execution time, rather than Now (fyi to ping commenters use _@UserName_ )

Comment: when you say "noticing slippage" you mean the job doesn't start exactly on the second you are expecting it to start? Or the whole thing takes longer to run than you are expecting? Without having looked at the details of your code, I would remind: (A) crontab on linux is not guaranteed to start exactly at the top of the minute (variable to what else CPU is doing), and (B) fetching data across the internet takes a variable amount of time depending on time of day, maybe you're just seeing variation in how long it takes for the endpoint to come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the scheduled time in absolute terms, rather than as a differential from `Now`.  (Now will always be some amount of time after the last scheduled time, so will always creep)

```
Sub xmlData()
    Static ScheduleTime As Variant '  Statis retains value between executions
    Dim aInterval As String

    ' other code
    ' ...

    If ScheduleTime = 0 Then
        ' initialise on first execution
        ScheduleTime = Now + TimeValue(aInterval)
    Else
        ' schedule based on last scheduled time
        '   this assumes execution time is always less than interval
        ScheduleTime = ScheduleTime + TimeValue(aInterval)
    End If

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(aInterval), "xmlData"

End Sub
```